# Error in JSON reading

Tags: android, json

I am creating an application in which everything goes fine but when the code in front activity call the Read method of JSONReader class it throws error. I crosschecked the code of Reading JSON from internet as well as my colleagues but they said its fine. I couldn't able to locate the exact error.

I tried putting LOG every place where I suspect but nothing helped and throws NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as the main reader is not working and no data is getting fetched.

Any one could help.

Here is the JSON Reader class and AsynkTask

**JSONReader.java**

```
public class JSONReader {

    JSONObject json = null;

    public JSONObject JSONRead(String url){

        try
        {
            StringBuilder jsonStr = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream is = null;

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpentity.getContent();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){

                jsonStr.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = new JSONObject(jsonStr.toString());
            is.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(">>>>>" + json.toString());
        return json;
    }

}
```

**AsynkTask**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> 
    {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private String value;
        private String valueimg;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WeatherHome.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONReader jsonr = new JSONReader();

            JSONObject jo = jsonr.JSONRead(url);
            Log.e(">>>>", ">>>>>" + jo.toString());
            return jo;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try 
            {
                Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>> On Post Execute", ">>>>>>>>>." + json);
                HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jObj = json.getJSONObject(DATA);
                JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray(WEATHER);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {



                    json = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String date = json.getString(DATE);
                    String TempMAXC = json.getString(MAXTEMPC);
                    String TempMinC = jObj.getString(MINTEMPC);

                    JSONArray description = json.getJSONArray(W_DESC);

                    for (int j = 0; j < description.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jObjDesc = description.getJSONObject(j);
                        value = jObjDesc.getString(VAL);
                    }   


                    JSONArray image = json.getJSONArray(W_IMG);

                    for (int k = 0; k < image.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject jObjImage = image.getJSONObject(k);
                        valueimg = jObjImage.getString(VAL_IMG);
                    }

                    hmap.put(DATE, date);
                    hmap.put(MAXTEMPC, TempMAXC);
                    hmap.put(MINTEMPC, TempMinC);
                    hmap.put(VAL, value);
                    hmap.put(VAL_IMG, valueimg);

                    array.add(hmap);

                    Log.d("ArrayList", array.toString());
                }

                list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(WeatherHome.this, array,
                        R.layout.custom_layout, new String[] { DATE, MAXTEMPC,
                                MINTEMPC, VAL, VAL_IMG }, new int[] {
                                R.id.tvDate, R.id.tvMaxTemp, R.id.tvMinTemp,
                                R.id.tvValue, R.id.weathercondition }));

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**LOG Error**

```
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.ourcast.pocketweather.JSONReader.JSONRead(JSONReader.java:49)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.ourcast.pocketweather.WeatherHome$JSONParse.doInBackground(WeatherHome.java:91)
03-05 19:25:01.780: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.ourcast.pocketweather.WeatherHome$JSONParse.doInBackground(WeatherHome.java:1)
```

**Note :** Line number 91 in WeatherHome is the call to the JSONRead method and line number 1 is obviously package statement.

Comment: Post your AsyncTask class code.

Comment: json = new JSONObject(jsonStr.toString()); @Raghunanadan

Comment: @Saggy did you check the response is not null

Comment: YEs I checked it from website I am getting it.

Comment: @PiyushGupta added the code of AsynkTask buddy.

Comment: @Saggy try `HttpEntity httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();` then `String res = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity)` then `Log.i(".....",res);`. See if it logs anything

Comment: @Saggy : print `jsonStr.toString()` in log and also use `jsonStr.append(line);` instead of `jsonStr.append(line + "\n");` because response is JSON so no need to add new line in String

Comment: @Raghunandan Implemented that, error still persists.

Comment: @Saggy looks like there is no response. Check it again

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK That too not working in log. Still Null Pointer Exception is there.

Comment: @Raghunandan I used the URL = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Gandhinagar&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=vh988wvnqkre5a5w3ywm4sp9" and from the website I am getting the response. Its working smoothly

Comment: @Saggy then you should see the response in the log.

Comment: @Raghunandan I was getting it earlier but now, no response no log nothing working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added the minimum required version as Cupcake. I have changed it to API 11 or you can do it to 8 also. Also I have changed this line  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) in WeatherHome.java to @TargetApi(Build.New_Version). It worked for me and I am getting data from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is a very sensitive json parse object. It is very easily failed if there is any invalid character inside the sentences.

In your case, I think JSONException is thrown when parsing jsonStr due to "\n".

Replace following line by remove "\n"

```
jsonStr.append(line + "\n");
```

to

```
jsonStr.append(line);
```

Comment: Changed that already but I guess that is not the error I am getting coz the error is still the same.